# local variables referenced from an inner class

Tags: java, javafx

I've been playing around with JavaFX lately and I just figured out how to use `MouseEvent`s, I wanted to make a program where when you click, it grabs your `X` and `Y` and creates a circle in that place.

I get the error `local variables referenced from an inner class` when I try this. I was going to use a lambda, but I couldn't figure out how.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.scene.shape.Circle;
public class circle extends Application{
    Scene scene;
    VBox v;
    public void start(Stage stage){
        double x = 0;
        double y = 0;
        v = new VBox(10);
        scene = new Scene(v, 300, 300);
        scene.setOnMousePressed(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>(){
            public void handle(MouseEvent e)
            {
                x = e.getX();
                y = e.getY();
            }
        });
        Circle circle = new Circle();
        circle.setCenterX(x);
        circle.setCenterY(y);
        v.getChildren().add(circle);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Even if your code compiled, it wouldn't update the position of the circle. You set the `centerX` and `centerY` of the circle just once, at a time when `x=0` and `y=0`. If you were allowed to access (non-final, non-effectively-final) local variables in the inner class, all you would be doing would be to update `x` and `y`, not the circle's `centerX` and `centerY` properties.

You just need

```
public void start(Stage stage){
    v = new VBox(10);
    scene = new Scene(v, 300, 300);
    Circle circle = new Circle();
    v.getChildren().add(circle);
    scene.setOnMousePressed(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>(){
        public void handle(MouseEvent e)
        {
            circle.setCenterX(e.getX());
            circle.setCenterY(e.getY());
        }
    });
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();
}
```

The lambda expression version looks like

```
public void start(Stage stage){
    v = new VBox(10);
    scene = new Scene(v, 300, 300);
    Circle circle = new Circle();
    v.getChildren().add(circle);
    scene.setOnMousePressed(e -> {
        circle.setCenterX(e.getX());
        circle.setCenterY(e.getY());
    });
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();
}
```

In versions of Java prior to Java8, you would need to declare `circle` as final, which you can readily do:

```
final Circle circle = new Circle();
```

Answer (score 0):

The error message is telling you what the problem is: your local variables, `x` and `y`, are being referenced in an inner class -- your `EventHandler`.  You need to declare `x` and `y` as members of your `Circle` class (which should be capitalized by convention, btw), not as local variables in the `start` function.  Then you will be able to set them in your `EventHandler`.